# Dynamically change between .ttf files Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, custom-font

I'm using a custom font in my app and need change the font attribute to bold which as far as I can tell is not done simply.

I have already managed to dynamically change colour and attributes for the default font using the resource dictionary:

```
<Color x:Key="LabelColor">White</Color>
<FontAttributes x:Key="LabelFontAtt">None</FontAttributes>
```

and then using MVVM changing the colour and attribute in my ViewModel:

```
App.Current.Resources["LabelColor"] = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#01bf89");
App.Current.Resources["LabelFontAtt"] = FontAttributes.Bold;
```

From a previous question I've already learned how to set my custom font as default for all labels with:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <OnPlatform.Android>JosefinSlab-Regular.ttf#JosefinSlab-Regular</OnPlatform.Android>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to switch between `JosefinSlab-Regular.ttf` and `JosefinSlab-Bold.ttf` but I've had little success with doing so. Is it possible to do it in a variation of what I've already done with attributes and colour or should it be done another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current setup you could create a second style like such:

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="BoldLabel">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <OnPlatform.Android>JosefinSlab-Bold.ttf#JosefinSlab-Bold</OnPlatform.Android>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then swap out the `Style` the same way you swap out the `TextColor` based on the Key in the `Style`.

I obviously don't know what functionality you're trying to implement but from what you're saying it seems like you're putting UI logic (such as colors) in your ViewModel which goes against how MVVM should be used in Xamarin Forms. If you want to change colors and styles based on data in your ViewModel you could also look into [Triggers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/) which is something that exists on the UI side only so you get a clean separation of ViewModel logic and UI logic.

Comment: You are of course quite right regarding MVVM and I'll keep it in mind for refactoring